# Crear un enlace con javaScript y cambiar un atributo class en una url de destino

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Soy novato en esto, mi pregunta sería:
¿Es posible enlazar a una url con JavaScript y en la url de destino cambiar una etiqueta class?

Tengo esta parte en html, son pestañas de bootstrap 5. Lo que pretendo hacer es mediante un enlace desde otra url poder cambiar la clase active para se muestre la pestaña activa cuando enlace con cada contenido.
Es decir desde otra página poder enlazar al contenido 1 y que este se muestre activo, otro enlace al contenido 2 y que este se muestre activo, etc. ¿Es posible?
Muchas gracias de antemano

```
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs row d-flex align-items-center">
            <li class="nav-item col-3 pestana"> <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">
              <h4 class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-xxl-block d-lg-none">Contenido 1</h4>
              </a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item col-3 pestana"> <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">
              <h4 class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-xxl-block d-lg-none">Contenido 2</h4>
              </a> </li>
          </ul>
```

He añadido los Ids a cada pestaña (Item-1, Item-2...) y al contenido de cada pestaña (tab-1, tab-2...) Al ejecutar este código remarca en negro la pestaña indicada pero no cambia las clases de la pestaña y su contenido

```js
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if (hash) {
    (new bootstrap.Tab(document.querySelector(hash))).show();
}
```

Debería poder cambiar las clases active en los Ids "item" y la clase active y show en los Ids "tab"

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs row d-flex align-items-center">
  <li class="nav-item col-3 pestana"> <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1" id="item-1">
    <h4 class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-xxl-block d-lg-none">Item 1</h4>
    </a> </li>
  <li class="nav-item col-3 pestana"> <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2" id="item-2">
    <h4 class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-xxl-block d-lg-none">Item 2</h4>
    </a> </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active show" id="tab-1">
    <h4>Contenido Item 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2">
    <h4>Contenido Item 2</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

He intentado cambiarle la clase desde el código sin éxito.
Muchas gracias de antemano

```js
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if (hash) {
    (new bootstrap.Tab(document.querySelector(hash))).className="active show";
}
```

Comment: Tienes acceso a la segunda página para agregar css?? o es externa??

Comment: Si, tengo acceso puedo añadir/modificar css. Gracias

Comment: Gracias @Yussef
Al ejecutar el código remarca con un recuadro negro la pestaña, pero no cambia la clase y no se muestra el contenido. Debería debería poder cambiar la clase tanto en la pestaña como en el contenido. Añado comentario a la descripción.

Comment: Probaste con el segundo método (por querystring)?

Comment: Si, pero no hace nada. Estoy utilizando html, el enlace es de este tipo www.mipagina.com/algoaca.html?tab=tab-1

Comment: Lo que pasa es tu colocaste otros id's dentro los <li>, tu les llamaste item-1, items-2, etc. Entonces deberías poner www.mipagina.com/algoaca.html?tab=item-1.

Comment: Si, probé de varias formas pero no soy capaz de cambiarle las clases para que se active. Con la primera opción crea un borde negro sobre la pestaña pero no despliega el contenido correspondiente. Debería poder cambiar las clases tanto a Item como a tab para que se active la pestaña y muestre el contenido correspondiente.

Comment: Es que no tienes que cambiar clases, debes poner la función que te dejé en la respuesta. Ese código está probado y funciona

Comment: Pues no sé que estaré haciendo mal, desde estos enlaces puedes ver lo que me está pasando. 
Opción 1. [enlace] (https://yuyo.neocities.org/tabs-bootstrap/pruebatabs1.html#item-3). 
Marca el item nº3 pero el contenido que se muestra es el del nº1.  Si cambias el nº del item en la url siempre muestra el contenido del nº1
Opción 2 [enlace] (https://yuyo.neocities.org/tabs-bootstrap/pruebatabs2.html?tab=item-3)
En esta opción no muestra cambios. 
También probé a quitar las clases iniciales active de Item y show de tab por si interfiere de alguna manera. Gracias

Comment: El código tienes que ponerlo al final del todo. O también puedes crear un evento onload y ponerlo dentro. Pero lo esencial es que el código se ejecute luego de que carga la página y luego que cargas las librerías de bootstrap

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear un pequeño script en la página destino, además tienes que colcar una Id para cada pestaña

```
<a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1" id="tab-1">
```

Y así sucesivamente para todos

Luego tienes, al menos, 2 formas

### Por Hash parameter

Esto es un hash en la url:

> [www.mipagina.com/algoaca#tab-1](http://www.mipagina.com/algoaca#tab-1)

Este el código que debes poner en la página destino

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash) {
    (new bootstrap.Tab(document.querySelector(hash))).show();
}
```

### Por Querystring params

> [www.mipagina.com/algoaca?tab=tab-1](http://www.mipagina.com/algoaca?tab=tab-1)

Este el código que debes poner en la página destino

```
var qp = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
if (qp.has('tab')) {
    (new bootstrap.Tab(document.getElementById(qp.get('tab')))).show();
}
```